# In Illustrator, is it possible to preview both outlines and bitmaps at the same time

Tags: adobe-illustrator, outline

This is my use-case: I am generating about 20 postcards that are simply artwork on a white backround. The scans of the artwork all have a white border, but sometimes the border is not even on all four sides. It would be great if I could see the outlines of the postcards (which are just rectangles with no strokes) AS WELL as the bitmap images on the artworks, so I can tell if the artwork is centred in the postcard. However **View -> Outline** just shows the outlines and **View -> GPU Preview** just shows the artwork as it will be printed.

I have found another method that works: Having a duplicate layer of the postcard rectangles with a black stroke instead. I make this layer visible to center the images in the postcards, then turn if off again. But ideally there would be a simpler way to do this. I am loathe to have a layer that always shows the outlines on the screen but then doesn't print them (which I could set in Layer Options), as this may confuse other people who have to work with the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize *layers*.

It's possible to have some layers in Outline Mode and other layers in Preview mode.

Hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> when clicking the **visibility icon** in the **Layers Panel** to toggle a layer between Outline/Preview.

The eyeball icon will become hollow when a layer is set to outline mode...

[image]

Note this **only works for Layers and Sub-Layers**. It will not work on objects, groups, clipping groups, etc. However, you can generally create a layer structure to compensate, such as having your raster images on individual layers.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I'll try that now.